# Adding a Terminal into a swing application

Tags: java, swing, terminal

I am making an application in java and I want to have a terminal as part of my GUI.
Is it possible to get the system terminal (or cmd if windows), and have it as part of my GUI in a panel ?

If so do I need a library like http://code.google.com/p/dragonconsole/ or there is some "default" way of getting the standard system terminal ? Thanks

Comment: dragonconsole looks very good. If you strip the included font then it has just 93kB.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I don't think a console/terminal library is provided by the java language. However, you can use the [`Process`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/api/java/lang/Process.html) and [`Runtime`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/api/java/lang/Runtime.html) classes to mimic the desired behaviour and interface with your native system, and use `JTextArea` + `JTextField` for showing and issuing commands in your GUI console.
Looking at the link you provided, I'd say dragonconsole might be a good option if you don't want to code a lot yourself. In any case, it depends on what exactly you intend to use your console for. But why re-invent hot water, right?

Comment: I am making a simple Java IDE. The purpose of the terminal will be similar to the one found in netbeans/eclipse, although I will also use it to display compile errors as well as run code. You think I can do that with the methods you mentioned ?

Comment: Yes, I think the `Process` and `Runtime` classes provide what you need to run commands to compile, run and show output/errors from your applications. `Runtime.exec()` allows you to run commands on the underlying system with many options, and returns a `Process` object through which you can access its I/O streams. It can take some trial and error to learn how exactly these classes work together ([some pitfalls](http://www.javaworld.com/javaworld/jw-12-2000/jw-1229-traps.html)). You might also want to make use of `System` to interact with environment variables such as class path and the like.

Comment: http://commons.apache.org/exec/tutorial.html was the solution. Thanks for answering.

Comment: My pleasure to help. Didn't know apache exec yet, thanks for the link! Good luck with the IDE!