# how can I run a command in XTERM console and then close it using java

Tags: java, bash, shell, xterm

I am using java and from there trying to 
1)open a xterm window which executes some command and
2)then should exit automatically after the execution and this execution should be visible

I mean to say that after executing the command it terminates.
The following code I am using :

```
 Runtime rt =Runtime.getRuntime();
 String i[]={"xterm","-e","sh example.sh"+"; bash"};
 Process p=null;
 try {
      p=rt.exec(i);
 }
```

"; bash"  - I am using it to let the window open during execution of the command but have no idea how to close it automatically once the execution completes.
Could I get some hints on this issue please ?

Comment: So what you need isn't *really* XTerm, but a terminal emulator? Why not a Java-based one? [That's been asked before](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9179329/adding-a-terminal-into-a-swing-application), but not fully fleshed out. [gritty](https://code.google.com/p/gritty/) also looks interesting.

Comment: Thanks David for your suggestion but I dont know about APACHE what has been described in the link that u mentioned. ANyway Is not there any possibility to close the XTERM window after command execution?

Comment: Are you really just trying to show the output of a command, possibly allowing interaction, as it's running?

Comment: I just want it to show the command , no interaction. As soon as the execution over it should close the xterm

Comment: Then why can't you just exec sample.sh from Java, capture stdout/stderr, and show them to the user directly?