# How do I insert a linux terminal into my java application

Tags: java

How do I embed a linux terminal into my JAVA application. 
(can be into a panel or something like this)

I tried to use

```
Runtime rt = Runtime.getRuntime();
  Process proc = rt.exec("xterm");
```

(I tried also `ProcessBuilder`)

But the xterm window is opened outside of my application.
I need it embedded in my application

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Adding a Terminal into a swing application](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9179329/adding-a-terminal-into-a-swing-application)